# Run tests identified by a name pattern in Bndtools/Bnd

Tags: bnd, bndtools

In a bundle that holds integration tests, I would like all classes whose names end with `Test` to be considered as tests and be executed when launching *OSGi Framework JUnit Tests*.

The `Test-Classes` directive in the `bnd.bnd` file seems to be the right place to specify this. However, the documentation for the `classes` macro at http://bnd.bndtools.org/macros/classes.html is sparse.

Therefore, my question is how to form the directive to include all classes ending with `Test` along the lines of

```
Test-Cases: ${classes that end with Test}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experiments so far revealed, that this directive does the trick:

```
Test-Cases: ${classes;CONCRETE;NAMED;*Test}
```

`CONCRETE` ensures that only concrete types are considered, e.g. excludes abstract types. And `NAMED` followed by the pattern `*Test` takes only those classes into account whose names end with Test.

Since JUnit 4 can only execute *public tests*, another constraint to consider might be `PUBLIC`. For example:

```
Test-Cases: ${classes;CONCRETE;PUBLIC;NAMED;*Test}
```

On the other hand, you may prefer to let JUnit fail non-public tests rather than silently ignoring them (if `PUBLIC` was specified).